# Code does not execute due to time out - How to optimize it

Tags: python-3.x

I'm playing around on CodeWars but it doesn't execute my code because of time out.

https://www.codewars.com/kata/playing-with-digits/train/python 
There is the link to the kata.

```
def dig_pow(n, p):

    x = 0

    for i in str(n):
        new_sum = int(str(n)[1]) ** (p+int(i)-1)

    while x <= new_sum/2:
        for x in range(int(round(new_sum/2))):
            if x * n == new_sum:
                return x

    return -1
```

Can't validate my reasoning because there is a time out.

Comment: Just run it locally and profile it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you hit an infinite loop with the `while` statement, thus the time-out is triggered on the Codewars platform.

Try to simplify the solution to this Kata, there is no need to use a `while` loop here, think about the value you have to return.

(Hint: try to use a `%` operator to check if one value can be divided by another without a remainder).